# Adding data into a table and saving it into a database

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a form when the user inputs the number of rows of the table which corresponds to number of subjects.I want the user to insert data into this table's columns or to fill it.How can i make this because my table just stands there chillin' and i can't insert data into it.
This is my code. Please someone shows me how to insert data into the columns of this table instead of phrases"one" and "two" i've used for demonstration.This code doesn't have errors so works very well.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>
 </title>
</head>
<body>
Insert nr of subjects  
<input type="text" id="row"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Sub </button>
<div id="container"></div><!--hapesira qe i kemi lene tabeles ne faqe-->
<script>

function myFunction(){


    //Get the value the user gave
    var nr = document.getElementById("row").value;
    //e kthej ne int nga string qe esht
    var c=parseInt(nr);
    var div=document.getElementById("container");
     div.innerHTML = " ";
      div.innerHTML += "<table border='1' id='table'>";
     document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td>SUBJECT</td><td>POINTS</td></tr>"; 

      for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {

        //Write the rows and cells
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td>  one </td><td>  two </td></tr>";
}
}
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code to insert inputs instead of "one" and "two", with classes `subject` and `points`. To store this information you will have to grab each row of your table and pull out the value of those inputs, and store it in the database.

```
function myFunction(){


    //Get the value the user gave
    var nr = document.getElementById("row").value;
    //e kthej ne int nga string qe esht
    var c=parseInt(nr);
    var div=document.getElementById("container");
     div.innerHTML = " ";
      div.innerHTML += "<table border='1' id='table'>";
     document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td>SUBJECT</td><td>POINTS</td></tr>"; 

      for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {

        //Write the rows and cells
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td><input type="text" class="subject" /></td><td><input type="text" class="points"/></td></tr>';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Right answer!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to store those data :subject and points into a database? I did this:<tr><td><input type="text" class="subject" name="subject" /></td>   and then used this name as a $POST var like $POST[$subject] to store in the database but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

You use HTML input elements to allow the user to enter data into a form. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: ok i know this but i want the user to enter data in this table i ve created.Is  this possible?So i want to use this table as a form

Comment: Create the table with input fields rather than "one" and "two". You can create input fields the same way you create table cells: by adding the text to the js string.

Answer (score 0):

Please add input elements when you are adding rows. Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>
 </title>
</head>
<body>
Insert nr of subjects  
<input type="text" id="row"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Sub </button>
<div id="container"></div><!--hapesira qe i kemi lene tabeles ne faqe-->
<script>

function myFunction(){


    //Get the value the user gave
    var nr = document.getElementById("row").value;
    //e kthej ne int nga string qe esht
    var c=parseInt(nr);
    var div=document.getElementById("container");
     div.innerHTML = " ";
      div.innerHTML += "<table border='1' id='table'>";
     document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td>SUBJECT</td><td>POINTS</td></tr>"; 

      for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {

        //Write the rows and cells
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='text' id= 'sub'> </td><td><input type='text' id='points'></td></tr>";
}
}
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Cheers !

Comment: Your code will create multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Yes, I know he can append a variable into id, was just giving idea. The question in itself is very basic :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot SachinThapa